# Reporting Server deploy - Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to deploy a report from Visual Studio to a Reporting Server which is not running on my local computer and I am getting this error:
   Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary

I can deploy the report to my local Reporting Server but when I tried to deploy the same report to another Reporting Server then is when I am getting that error message.

I am running Visual Studio 2017
I have installed Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools version (15.1.61707.200)

The Reporting Server where I tried to deploy the report is running Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Reporting Server.
Target SQL Server 2012

Please any advice or suggestion to fix this problem.

Regards;
Sergio

Comment: This could be a permissions issue. Try using an admin level account to test.

Comment: Hi:
Thanks for your reply, but I don't think it is a permission related problem.
I have tried with a super user account and I cannot deploy the report from Visual Studio.

Comment: Found the solution:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68f09a17-23b6-4e2f-8dd2-f532e02eb563/unable-to-deploy-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are having the same problem as me, I have found the solution:
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68f09a17-23b6-4e2f-8dd2-f532e02eb563/unable-to-deploy-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

Please install the latest package for Microsoft Reporting Services Projects.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio#overview